# How to make pocketsphinx recognize keyphrases

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I tried to make a simple speech recognition script in python using pocketsphinx library.
It should work like this: it listens continously and when it hears a certain keyphrase it enters if statement.

On google and the only example of a liveSpeech with keyphrase is this one: [Python Voice Recognition Library - Always Listen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394329/python-voice-recognition-library-always-listen).
But it has only 1 keyphrase.

I managed to make something that runs but the results are not good. The code below iterates in the for loop for each word I pronounce more than once (it iterates for every hypothesis). And because he does that I cannot make keyphrases with more than 1 word which is horrible.

```py
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model')
liveSpeech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, '8415.lm'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, '8415.dic'),
)

for phrase in liveSpeech:
    print('---')
    print(phrase.segments(detailed=True))
    liveText = phrase.hypothesis()
    print('conf', phrase.confidence())
    print(phrase.hypothesis())
    print('---')
    if liveText == 'SIRI START MUSIC':
        print('*** MUSIC ***')
    elif liveText == 'SIRI READ INBOX':
        print('*** READ ***')
    elif liveText == 'SIRI WRITE NEW EMAIL':
        print('*** WRITE ***')
```

I will also post the .dic and .lm file I made for LiveSpeech object
.dic

```
EMAIL   IY M EY L
INBOX   IH N B AA K S
MUSIC   M Y UW Z IH K
NEW N UW
NEW(2)  N Y UW
READ    R EH D
READ(2) R IY D
SIRI    S IH R IY
START   S T AA R T
WRITE   R AY T
```

and .lm

```
\1-grams:
-1.0280 </s> -0.3010
-1.0280 <s> -0.2583
-1.5051 EMAIL -0.2583
-1.5051 INBOX -0.2583
-1.5051 MUSIC -0.2583
-1.5051 NEW -0.2872
-1.5051 READ -0.2872
-1.0280 SIRI -0.2583
-1.5051 START -0.2872
-1.5051 WRITE -0.2872

\2-grams:
-0.3010 <s> SIRI 0.0000
-0.3010 EMAIL </s> -0.3010
-0.3010 INBOX </s> -0.3010
-0.3010 MUSIC </s> -0.3010
-0.3010 NEW EMAIL 0.0000
-0.3010 READ INBOX 0.0000
-0.7782 SIRI READ 0.0000
-0.7782 SIRI START 0.0000
-0.7782 SIRI WRITE 0.0000
-0.3010 START MUSIC 0.0000
-0.3010 WRITE NEW 0.0000

\3-grams:
-0.7782 <s> SIRI READ
-0.7782 <s> SIRI START
-0.7782 <s> SIRI WRITE
-0.3010 NEW EMAIL </s>
-0.3010 READ INBOX </s>
-0.3010 SIRI READ INBOX
-0.3010 SIRI START MUSIC
-0.3010 SIRI WRITE NEW
-0.3010 START MUSIC </s>
-0.3010 WRITE NEW EMAIL
```

those are made with http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html

I expected that when I say at microphone "SIRI START MUSIC" to see

```
*** MUSIC ***
```

on command prompt. But I see repeated words, something like this (the confidence i suppose is per word?):

```
conf 0.37786707159431465
SIRI

conf 0.4968430593575863
START NEW

conf 0.2751470548287679
NEW

conf 1.0
NEW
```

Please, how to improve my code to work the way I need.
Thanks!

Comment: You need keyword list instead of LM. Time to check the tutorial http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230722/pocketsphinx-recognizes-random-phrases-in-a-silence/35234564#35234564

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. So I made a kphs.txt containing
`WRITE NEW EMAIL /1e-40/
READ INBOX /1e-20/
START MUSIC /1e-30/` and than I add this line of code decoder.set_kws('keyphrase', kphs_path). What I do with this decoder? I seen it used but on audiofiles not on LiveSpeech object. I checked the whole website  page by page for python examples and documentation and found nothing that I can use. Maybe for more advanced people those 2-3 lines of code are enough but I need bigger examples

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
lm=os.path.join(model_path, '8415.lm'),
```

try

```
kws=os.path.join(model_path, 'kws.list'),
```

Comment: so I commented `#lm=os.path.join(model_path, '8415.lm'),` and put `kws=os.path.join(model_path, 'kphs.list'),` The program run with no compile error but no keyphrase was triggered in the for `for phrase in liveSpeech:` (tried with no other conditions just to see it work, but it didnt work) I also tried with no phrases and just words in the file and also I tried with the default cmudict-en-us.dict file instead of dic=os.path.join(model_path, '8415.dic'). Thanks for the time. If u have any other idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a file in the current directory called kws.txt with the following contents:

```
siri start music /1e-40/
siri read inbox /1e-40/
siri write new email /1e-40/
```

This script loads in the file and monitors the live input for the key phrases:

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech

speech = LiveSpeech(lm=False, kws="./kws.txt")
for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase.segments(detailed=True))
```

Example output:

```
[('siri start music ', -874, 1857, 1984)]
[('siri read inbox ', -1120, 2018, 2157)]
[('siri write new email ', -1364, 2614, 2752)]
```